# on ng-click all three values in my input box are being triggered which have different button for different input box (new to angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have three input boxes, on ng-click set d1, only the value in first input box should be sent and the value should replace the value of "calibration.result.calibration.d1" with "calib.calib.d1". but when I click on d1 all the input boxes are being triggered. Can anyone look into my code and help me? 
TIA

Here is my code

```
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-md">D-1</button>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">D-2</button>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">D-3</button>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div ng-cloak ng-model="calibration">{{calibration.result.calibration.d1}}</div>
                            <div ng-cloak ng-model="calib">{{calib.calib.d1}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div ng-cloak ng-model="calibration">{{calibration.result.calibration.d2}}</div>
                            <div ng-cloak ng-model="calib">{{calib.calib.d2}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div ng-cloak ng-model="calibration">{{calibration.result.calibration.d3}}</div>
                            <div ng-cloak ng-model="calib">{{calib.calib.d3}}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
                <br>
                <form ng-submit="setCalibration()">
                    <input style="width:60px;text-align: center" type="number" step="0.1" placeholder="2.5" name="d1" ng-model="d1">
                    <input style="width:60px;text-align: center" type="number" step="0.1" placeholder="2.5" name="d2" ng-model="d2">
                    <input style="width:60px;text-align: center" type="number" step="0.1" placeholder="2.5" name="d3" ng-model="d3">

                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="D1" ng-click="disp = 'd1'">Set </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="D2" ng-click="disp = 'd2'">Set D2</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="D3" ng-click="disp = 'd3'">Set D3</button>-->

                    </div>

                </form>
```

app.js

```
    $scope.setCalibration = function () {
    var dataSent = {
        uid: $scope.uid,
        dispenser: $scope.disp,
        calib: {
            d1: $scope.d1,
            d2: $scope.d2,
            d3: $scope.d3
        }
    };
    $scope.d1 = '';
    $scope.d2 = '';
    $scope.d3 = '';

    console.log($scope.disp);
    console.log(dataSent);
    console.log(dataSent.calib);
    $http.post('/v1/atm/calib/update', dataSent)
        .then(function (response) {

                $rootScope.calib = response.data;
                $scope.calibration = $rootScope.calib;
                console.log($scope.calibration);



                console.log($rootScope.calib);

            },
            function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            });
};
```

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<div>` elements.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be…  **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: tq georgeawg :)

Answer (score 0):

Ng-submit, according to the angular documentation:

> Enables binding AngularJS expressions to onsubmit events.

In JavaScript, an onsubmit event is fired whenever you press a form's submit button. So, setCalibration() is triggered whenever you click on the Set D1 submit button. setCalibration() seems to capture & update all 3 values, which is why you're seeing that behavior.

Comment: removing the Ng-submit and just using ng-click will sort the problem which is facing?